# Spring data jpa + hibernate + websphere 7 deployment support needed

Tags: spring, jpa, websphere, spring-data-jpa, websphere-7

We are trying to deploy a war in `websphere 7`, currently which supports only `JPA 1.0` and where we cannot upgrade to `JPA 2.0` and use it. So we are downgrading the application and deploy.

Currently using below spring-data-jpa, hibernate and spring version as below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.ga</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

> spring version : 3.2.5.RELEASE

But still we are getting this below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/EntityManager.getMetamodel()Ljavax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel;
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:145)
```

Please advice, how we can resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The fact that your server supports JPA1 doesn't mean you cannot use JPA2. Just package everything in your war, disable parent-first class loading and deploy. Instead of trying to hack things together with older versions.

Comment: if we deploy as it is without downgrading to jpa 1.0 version in persistence.xml and by disabling parent-first class loading, we are getting Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'persistence' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.

Comment: Then you have JPA 1 in your war or haven't included everything necessary in your war. Also you shouldn't use the versions of hibernate and spring-data-jpa but use a more recent version.

Comment: everything is included, it throws The following associated error message occurred: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:642)

Comment: Then you have incompatible versions... Probable a JPA 2.1 implementation and included JPA 2.0 API (or vice-versa).

Comment: Does spring data jpa supports JPA 1.0 ? why because i am using quite old spring data jpa 1.0.2.RELEASE . And why it is looking for 2.0 methods as mentioned in my first post

Comment: Spring Data JPA doesn't really care as that uses JPA. It is your JPA provider (in this case Hibernate) that supports a certain version. So depending on your hibernate version you need a 1.0, 2.0 or 2.1 API.

Comment: In this [link](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/) say **newer ORM releases are backwards compatible with older JPA versions (ex: ORM 4.3 with JPA 1.0). However, newer ORM releases may not be compatible with older JPA containers** . So can i use hibernate-entity- manager version 4.3.11.Final also ? Please correct if i am wrong

Comment: Well in this case my conclusion was a bit quick. Spring Data JPA needs at least JPA 2.0 as it requires some methods where added in JPA 2.0.

Comment: So there is no way other than installing the **WebSphere Application Server V7 Feature Pack for OSGi Applications and Java Persistence API 2.0** ?

Comment: No just include JPA 2.0 api in your war and disable parent-first class loading...

Comment: Sorry we could not resolve this issue, instead we are forcing server with patch install.

Comment: So instead of trying to fix it you are patching things. I would opt for fixing the issue. Have been running applications like that on different versions of web sphere. If it isn't working the error is in your dependencies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a shared library path having hibernate jars and by mapping to the application before starting the server worked out.